# F# Using Return Values From Async

Tags: asynchronous, f#

I'm trying to learn F# but I keep running into issues. The latest is using async. In the code below, I'm trying to run two long running operations and perform a calculation based on the result but I get an error "Async does not support the + operator". I have tried casting etc to get it to work but I'm not getting anywhere fast.

Could someone please explain where I'm going wrong.

Thanks.

```
let SumOfOpFaults =
    async{
        printfn "Getting Sum of Op Faults"
        return query {
            for a in AlarmResult do
            sumBy a.UserFaultTime
        }
    }

let SumOfMcFaults =
    async{
        printfn "Getting Sum of Machine Faults"
        return query {
            for a in AlarmResult do
            sumBy a.MachineFaultTime
        }
    }

[SumOfMcFaults; SumOfOpFaults]
|> Async.Parallel
|> Async.RunSynchronously
|> ignore

let total = SumOfOpFaults + SumOfMcFaults // <---Error Here
```

Comment: Why are you ignoring the result of `Async.RunSynchronously`?  That function will return your two parallel results in an array, then you just add the elements together normally...

Comment: Hi - the absolute honest answer is because I don't know what I'm doing, I'm still learning F#. Using your comments, I was able to sort it so thanks - I appreciate the time. If you could post it as an answer, I can accept.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`SumOfOpFaults` is defined as an `Async<'T>`. It will never change to a `'T` so you can't use `+` on it later.

`Async.Parallel` turns any sequence of `Async` computations into one `Async` computation that runs them in parallel and returns an array.

`Async.RunSynchronously` doesn't give you a result by side effects, but as a return value. So you just need to do this:

```
let total =
    [SumOfMcFaults; SumOfOpFaults]
    |> Async.Parallel
    |> Async.RunSynchronously
    |> Array.sum
```